# check if HashMap / Map contains a class variable in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'd like to start clarifying that I'm new to java so I also don't know exactly how to ask this (I also couldn't find any solutions here).

Okay so I've got this HashMap where I store a class for each key, and I need to check if a variable from that class in the HashMap is equal to `x`.

Informal example:

this is the HashMap content:

`{1: myClass("albert", "smith", 48), 2: myClass("jason", "small", 50)}`

I need to know if `"smith"` is in that HashMap so that I can then compare it to `x`.

Thanks.

Comment: `myMap.values().stream().map(MyClass::getSurname).anyMatch("smith"::equals)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Person mapPerson = _map.keySet().stream().filter(person -> person.getName().equals("Smith")).findFirst().orElse(null);
if (mapPerson != null)
{
    // Already exists. Place your code
}
```